# Link HTML site with MVC site's Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm building a HTML page on button click, it will transfer data from localStorage at HTML page to MVC site's action and process action then save data at MVC site

this is my HTML button 's function:

```
function OH10() {            
            var url1 = "@Url.Action('createFuel','FuelExtras')";
            debugger;
            for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
                var key = localStorage.key(i);
                var val = localStorage.getItem(key);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: url1,
                    data: val,
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function () {
                        alert("Data has been added successfully.");
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("Error while inserting data");
                    }
                });
            }
};
```

And MVC site 's action:

```
[HttpPost]
        [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
        public ActionResult createFuel(FuelExtra fuelExtra)
        {
            db.FuelExtras.Add(fuelExtra);
            db.SaveChanges();
            string message = "SUCCESS";
            return Json(new { Message = message, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet });
        }
```

Any Suggestions guys?
And 1 more question is right now in development, I've build 2 sites in same Solution, but when I deploy it to intranet i have to separate it into 2 sites. Is it ok?

Comment: `[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]` is unnecessary in MVC and should be removed. Also `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` is wrong if you're not using `JSON.stringify` against the data. Can you show `FuelExtra` class properties (just edit the question to include it)?

Comment: Thank @TetsuyaYamamoto , here is my FuelExtra.cs :public partial class 
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string CaptainEmpNo { get; set; }
        public string AirCraft { get; set; }
        public string FlightNo { get; set; }
        public string DepartureAirport { get; set; }
        public string ArrivalAirport { get; set; }

Comment: Lately when i create a view in MVC site and using the same button code, it work, but when i copy this code to different HTML page, i got error evertime.

Comment: What kind of error you've got? Can you provide contents of `val` variable (with `console.log(val)`), because the correct `data` setting should be `data: { fuelExtra: val }`? By your current code, you're sending AJAX request multiple times instead of single request.

Comment: the error is can't connect to url @TetsuyaYamamoto, here is sample val :{
  "Fuel444": "{\"CaptainEmpNo\":\"4445\",\"AirCraft\":\"5555\",\"FlightNo\":\"444\",\"DepartureAirport\":\"HCM\",\"ArrivalAirport\":\"HN\",\"ReasonExtraFuel1\":\"Weather Enroute\",\"ExtraFuel1\":\"1112\",\"ReasonExtraFuel2\":\"\",\"ExtraFuel2\":\"\",\"ReasonExtraFuel3\":\"\",\"ExtraFuel3\":\"\",\"ReasonExtraFuel4\":\"\",\"ExtraFuel4\":\"\",\"Reason\":\"\",\"TotalExtraFuel\":\"1112\"}"
}

Comment: i wonder why i use the same view in MVC site, this code work, but when separate into new HTML page, it don't work anymore, is there something different i have to concern?@TetsuyaYamamoto. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found several mistakes in your example:

1) `System.Web.Services.WebMethod` only used in webforms, it cannot be used for `ActionResult` in MVC and should be removed.

2) The AJAX callback placed inside a loop, therefore it will execute multiple times instead of single request.

3) The passed data is the last `localStorage` value taken from `getItem()` function as single string, not a key-value pair reflecting model property names and their values.

Hence, by assuming you have this model:

```
public class FuelExtra
{
    public string CaptainEmpNo { get; set; } 
    public string AirCraft { get; set; } 
    public string FlightNo { get; set; } 
    public string DepartureAirport { get; set; } 
    public string ArrivalAirport { get; set; }

    // other properties
}
```

Then you should send key-value pair object as JSON string because the `contentType` setting has been set to `application/json` by `JSON.stringify()`, as in example below:

```js
function OH10() {            
    var key = []; // array of keys
    var val = []; // array of values

    var obj = {}; // combined KVP object

    var url1 = "@Url.Action("CreateFuel", "FuelExtras")";
    debugger;
    for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
        key.push(localStorage.key(i));
        val.push(localStorage.getItem(key));
    }

    for (var n = 0; n < key.length; n++) {
        obj[key[n]] = val[n]; // create KVP object from both arrays
    }

    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: url1,
       data: JSON.stringify({ fuelExtra: obj }), // convert KVP object to JSON string
       dataType: "json",
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       success: function (result) {
           alert("Data has been added successfully.");
       },
       error: function (xhr, status, err) {
           alert("Error while inserting data");
       }
    });
};
```

And the controller action should be like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateFuel(FuelExtra fuelExtra)
{
    db.FuelExtras.Add(fuelExtra);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return Json(new { Message = "SUCCESS" });
}
```

Since you're sending AJAX request as POST method, then `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` is unnecessary.

**Note:**

Make sure all key names inside passed JSON string from AJAX is the same as all property names declared inside `FuelExtra` class.

Comment: Sorry Tetsuya but it still got error "Error while inserting data" . I see that while debuging, it seem code stop at $.ajax and then jump to error right away, it not go to code "type" or anything?

Comment: Try using Fiddler or other tools to check request and response details, or utilize `alert(err)` to show the message. Also make sure the URL is right and accessible for request.